# Reassign the smartphone's shortcut buttons

Tags: android, html, smartphone

How do I reassign the smartphone's shortcut buttons(the four buttons on the bottom (back, menu, home and search)) (Due to "We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images.": http://www.letsgodigital.org/images/artikelen/1/android.jpg)

within my html5 webpage, so the user can search, go to the main page and open a website menu for faster access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "reassign the smartphone's shortcut buttons" from within your "html5 webpage", unless this "html5 webpage" is running in some container with specific support for this (e.g., PhoneGap).